# Redhat Linux - Disk configuration

Tags: linux, disk

I have 1 physical disk and configure into ONE VG. From ONE vg I configure into multiple LV (10 LV). for each LV, total size about 1TB. The I/O is about 750MB/s and the IOPS about 37000 IOPS.

Is there any performance impact by using ONE VG into multiple LV?

Answer (score 0):

A Volume Group is supposed to be used to create multiple Logical Volumes in it. Since you have only one underlying Physical Volume, there won't be any need to create more than one VGs.